# Mysql : How to get data from last July to Current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to get data for July

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
   WHERE MONTH(created) = 7
```

But How can I get data between last July to current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your query, I would go with :

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE MONTH(created) = 7 
AND (
( MONTH(CURDATE()) <= 7 AND YEAR(created) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 )
OR 
( MONTH(CURDATE()) > 7 AND YEAR(created) = YEAR(CURDATE()) )
)
```

If you want (like your asked in comments ) the data SINCE such time, go with :

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
    WHERE created <= CURDATE()
    AND (
    (
    MONTH(CURDATE()) <= 7
    AND created >= DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-07-01'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    )
    OR
    (
    MONTH(CURDATE()) > 7
    AND created >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-07-01')
    ));
```

Comment: I would change the conditions on `MONTH(CURDATE())` to be `<= 7` and `> 7`; if it is currently July, "last July" should refer to last year.

Comment: I need the data from last July to current data and last July can be this year or last year. For example this is month April now last July is April 2017. Now If we this month is December 2018 then last July will be July 2018.

Comment: If I have two data in 2017 July and 2018 July , according to your query both are coming, I need last one. Last july to now.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think you had future dates in your table, fixed it on the second query.

Comment: If I have 2017-07-29 and 2018-07-29 I need last one that means,  all data <= 2018-07-29 . according to your query I am getting all data <=  2017-07-29

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170078/discussion-between-satu-sultana-and-aurelien).

Answer (score 0):

used below query.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `tableName`
WHERE MONTH(created) = 7 
AND
(CASE WHEN (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) < 7) 
 THEN
       YEAR(created) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
 ELSE
       YEAR(created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
 END)
```

Comment: I need the data from last July to current data and last July can be this year or last year. For example this is month April now last July is April 2017. Now If we this month is December 2018 then last July will be July 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Bro Try now...

```
    SELECT * FROM  Table_Name
WHERE event_date between (case when month(GETDATE()) >6
                                then cast( concat(year( GETDATE()),'-07-01')as datetime)    
                                    else cast( concat(year( GETDATE())-1,'-07-01')   as datetime) 
                                    end)  and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want data *since* last July, then you need to find the date of last July.

```
select t.*
from t
where (month(now()) > 7 and t.created >= date(concat(year(now()), '-01-01')) or
      (month(now()) <= 7 and t.created >= date(concat(year(now()) - 1, '-01-01')) ;
```